# Вращение шара, с возможностью управлять с помощью событий

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, d3.js

Задача состоит в реализации вращения шара. Ниже должны быть три кнопки, при клике на соответствующую кнопку шар должен произвести вращение до соответствующего офиса.

[image: видео]

Comment: что конкретно в этом задании непонятного или Вы хотите готовое решение увидеть?

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть решение. Ибо ни одна из моих попыток не привела к результату

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит копать в сторону атрибута  transform. Просто настройте смещение и 3D трансформации с одной скоростью, чтоб эмулировать поворот шара. Может даже и в d3 есть более простой способ сделать это.